# Should I care about the DOM processing time in Newrelic Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, production-environment, pagespeed, newrelic

I am using Newrelic on my Ruby on Rails app? In the "Browser page load time" section, I can see a large portion of the loading time falls into the "DOM processing"(about 5 sec). I just want to know if this is normal? Should I be worrying about this and optimizing this more? There a lots of JS code in my app and many DOM are dynamically created, I think that is why its taking the most time to load. But the Firebug shows the load time is 6.18s (onload: 5.16s), seems to be pretty fast loading to me, and many js load a at the bottom of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Mine's even worse - ~1.2 seconds for me, but newrelic RUM shows ~5.5 seconds.  The new histogram view shows the outliers a bit better, but it's still frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to improve client load times, then yes, you should care :)  If not, don't worry about it.

https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work

Comment: Hi Scalayer, I been monitoring the DOM processing it event get up to 29sec per request. But the page load in my browser seems pretty fast still(Firebug still shows the load time is 6.18s (onload: 5.16s) or less). If I want to improve client load time, what should I look in to? the page is really simple and contains no images, but my worry is the JS code as its including many libs (Datatable, jQuery, bootstrap, ckeditor etc...), and many DOM are build dynamically in JS. If these libs and dynamic DOM are the cause, any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: I would probably look at optimizing those JS libraries.  New Relic is looking at averages across the time-window, so keep that mind.